# JQGrid Subgrid Error How can this be fixed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am trying to generate a JQgrid with Subgrid based on examples I came across online but instead of local data, I am using json service .

By Using nested JSON data, where the nested json data is used for the subgrid section.

When I try to create the grid, I keep getting this error "*SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 26 200 OK*"

What am I doing wrong or missing?

My code is below and my [Fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/615qovew/61/)

MY CODE

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var jsonData = {
      id: 48803,
      thingy: "DSK1",
      number: "02200220",
      status: "OPEN",
      subgridData: [{
        num: 1,
        item: "Item 1",
        qty: 3
      }, {
        num: 2,
        item: "Item 2",
        qty: 5
      }]
    },
    {
      id: 48769,
      thingy: "APPR",
      number: "77733337",
      status: "ENTERED",
      subgridData: [{
        num: 3,
        item: "Item 3",
        qty: 5
      }, {
        num: 2,
        item: "Item 2",
        qty: 10
      }]
    },
    mmddyyyy = "";
  /*********************************************************************/


  $("#grid").jqGrid({
    url: "/echo/json/",
    mtype: "POST",
    datatype: "json",
    postData: {
      json: JSON.stringify(jsonData)
    },
    height: 'auto',
    colNames: ['Inv No', 'Thingy', 'Number', 'Status'],
    colModel: [{
      name: 'id',
      width: 60,
      sorttype: "int",
      key: true
    }, {
      name: 'thingy',
      width: 90
    }, {
      name: 'number',
      width: 80,
      formatter: "integer"
    }, {
      name: 'status',
      width: 80
    }],
    gridview: true,
    autoencode: true,
    pager: '#pagerId',
    caption: "Stack Overflow Subgrid Example",
    subGrid: true,
    subGridOptions: {
      plusicon: "ui-icon-triangle-1-e",
      minusicon: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s",
      openicon: "ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-e"
    },
    shrinkToFit: false,

    subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
      var subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id + "_t",
        pager_id = "p_" + subgrid_table_id,
        localRowData = $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", row_id);
      $("#" + subgrid_id).html("<table id='" + subgrid_table_id + "'></table><div id='" + pager_id + "'></div>");
      $("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        data: localRowData.subgridData,
        colNames: ['No', 'Item', 'Qty'],
        colModel: [{
          name: "num",
          width: 80,
          key: true
        }, {
          name: "item",
          width: 130
        }, {
          name: "qty",
          width: 70,
          align: "right"
        }],
        rowNum: 20,
        idPrefix: "s_" + row_id + "_",
        pager: "#" + pager_id,
        autowidth: true,
        gridview: true,
        autoencode: true,
        sortname: "num",
        sortorder: "asc",
        height: "auto"
      }).jqGrid('navGrid', "#" + pager_id, {
        edit: false,
        add: false,
        del: false
      });
    }
  });


});
```

[MY Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/615qovew/60/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to fix the syntax error. The definition of the variable `jsonData`  in the form

```
var jsonData = {
        id: 48803,
        ...
    },
    {
        id: 48769,
        ...
    };
```

is false. You try to define `jsonData` as **array** of items. Thus the code fragment have to be fixed to

```
var jsonData = [{
        id: 48803,
        ...
    },
    {
        id: 48769,
        ...
    }];
```

Then you define `<table id="grid"></table>`, but create the grid using `$("#output").jqGrid({...});` in [your demo](https://jsfiddle.net/615qovew/60/). You have to use in both cases *the same* value if `id`.

Now, back to you main problem. You want to use `subgridData` property of the items of the data (`$(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", row_id).subgridData`) filled via `datatype: "json"`. The `datatype: "json"` means **server based** sorting, paging and filtering of the data. jqGrid don't fill *local* data (the `data` parameter). To fill `data` you have to inform jqGrid that the input data from the server contains *full data* (all the pages) and thus jqGrid should fill `data` option and to use *local* sorting, paging and filtering. Thus you should add

```
loadonce: true,
```

and

```
additionalProperties: ["subgridData"],
```

additionally to inform jqGrid to fill the items of local data with `subgridData` property together with the properties `id`, `thingy`, `number` and `status` (the columns of the main grid).

Finally you can remove unneeded pager divs and to use simplified form of the pager: `pager: true`. You should consider to use Font Awesome additionally: `iconSet: "fontAwesome"`.

The modified demo is https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/615qovew/64/, which uses the following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var jsonData = [{
      id: 48803,
      thingy: "DSK1",
      number: "02200220",
      status: "OPEN",
      subgridData: [{
        num: 1,
        item: "Item 1",
        qty: 3
      }, {
        num: 2,
        item: "Item 2",
        qty: 5
      }]
    },
    {
      id: 48769,
      thingy: "APPR",
      number: "77733337",
      status: "ENTERED",
      subgridData: [{
        num: 3,
        item: "Item 3",
        qty: 5
      }, {
        num: 2,
        item: "Item 2",
        qty: 10
      }]
    }],
    mmddyyyy = "",
    $grid = $("#output");
  /*********************************************************************/

  $grid.jqGrid({
    url: "/echo/json/",
    mtype: "POST",
    datatype: "json",
    postData: {
      json: JSON.stringify(jsonData)
    },
    colNames: ['Inv No', 'Thingy', 'Number', 'Status'],
    colModel: [{
      name: 'id',
      width: 60,
      sorttype: "int",
      key: true
    }, {
      name: 'thingy',
      width: 90
    }, {
      name: 'number',
      width: 80,
      formatter: "integer"
    }, {
      name: 'status',
      width: 80
    }],
    loadonce: true,
    additionalProperties: ["subgridData"],
    autoencode: true,
    pager: true,
    caption: "Stack Overflow Subgrid Example",
    subGrid: true,
    /*subGridOptions: {
      plusicon: "ui-icon-triangle-1-e",
      minusicon: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s",
      openicon: "ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-e"
    },*/
    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
    shrinkToFit: false,
    subGridRowExpanded: function(subgridDivId, rowid) {
      var $subgrid = $("<table id='" + subgridDivId + "_t'></table>"),
          subgridData = $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid).subgridData;

      $("#" + subgridDivId).append($subgrid);
      $subgrid.jqGrid({
        data: subgridData,
        colNames: ['No', 'Item', 'Qty'],
        colModel: [{
          name: "num",
          width: 80,
          key: true
        }, {
          name: "item",
          width: 130
        }, {
          name: "qty",
          width: 70,
          align: "right"
        }],
        rowNum: 20,
        idPrefix: "s_" + rowid + "_",
        pager: true,
        iconSet: "fontAwesome",
        autowidth: true,
        autoencode: true,
        sortname: "num"
      }).jqGrid('navGrid', {
        edit: false,
        add: false,
        del: false
      });
    }
  }).jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
    stringResult: true,
    searchOnEnter: false,
    defaultSearch: "cn"
  });

  $(window).on("resize", function() {
    var newWidth = $grid.closest(".ui-jqgrid").parent().width();
    $grid.jqGrid("setGridWidth", newWidth, true);
  }).triggerHandler("resize");
});
```

Comment: Thank you. By any chance do you know if jqgrid supports dynamic column creation? I am trying to generate a jqgrid table, based on json data where the number of column could vary.